# How do I contrast two lists, ignoring half of the information of each line?

Tags: python, set

I need to output a list of every package that exists in file1 that does not already exist in file2, but I can't figure out how to get the code to ignore the '=' and every character after it each line when it tries to subtract set(file2) from set(file1).
The problem is that each line of these two files is a filepath along with the name of the package. I.E.

file1    PerfectlyIdenticalInformation/package.rpm=/home/pasmoti/storage/package/package.rpm

file2    PerfectlyIdenticalInformation/package.rpm=/repostorage/repo/package/package.rpm

I can't remove the file path from file1 either, I will need that. I can't remove the file paths and put them back on either, there are a few different filepaths in each file.

The code so far:

```
file1 = []
file2 = []
with open('file1.txt') as f1
     file1 = f1.read().splitlines()
with open(file2.txt') as f2
     file2 = f2.read().splitlines()
diff = set(file1) - set(file2)
outfile = open ('Diff.txt','w')
for line in sorted (diff):
     outfile.write(line)
     outfile.write('/n')
```

This outputs a precise copy of whichever set is put first in the "diff = set - set" line, because it does not recognize any single line from the other as being identical due to the filepath in the name.

Comment: If you want the package.rpm values, why not parse that before you put it in a set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.